# How does this Mon Calamari cruiser land?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

I don't understand how the *Profundity* (the Mon Calamari cruiser that we saw in *Rogue One*) lands.

The bridge is on a long stalk at the bottom of the ship which implies that the only way it can land is by resting on the bridge, but surely it can't support all that weight.

So how are they able to land?

[image: Page from the Rogue One Visual Dictionary for The Profundity - a large and long starship with a big vertical stalk coming out of the bottom]

Comment: Landingships land, calamari lbobobbob ... sink.

Comment: I would assume that many of the ships seen in Star Wars were built in space and never land.  Maybe not this one, but certainly some - how would you land a Death Star for example?  Even Star Destroyers, the bottom is a sharp edge, if you land, it would tip over to one side.  Unless you built some *serious* legs on it which we've never seen...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It used to be established that Imperial class Star Destroyers are incapable of operating in an atmosphere, I don't know if that's still official canon or not.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You could presumably land it in a cradle, similar to (but much larger than) ones used by ocean-going ships in drydock. Of course, the question then is "why".

Comment: @Davidw that used to be the case but the Imperial Star Destroyer hovering over Jedha contradicts that and it is the new canon that they can hover in atmo if they have their engines at full power or some nonesense

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Profundity is confirmed in its [Star Wars Databank article](https://www.starwars.com/databank/the-profundity) to have been part of the [Exodus Fleet](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars-armada/images/9/9b/Swm30_card_mon-calamari-exodus-fleet.png/revision/latest?cb=20180104003913) that left the Mon Calamari homeworld when the Empire subjugated the surface. As such, it appears that **the ship can be docked (in an upright fashion) anywhere there's a large enough expanse of water.**

> **THE PROFUNDITY**
>
> *The Profundity began its life as a daring ruse: it was built as a tower in a city beneath Mon Cala’s northern ice floes, and launched into space when the Empire subjugated the planet. A quick conversion by Mon Calamari engineers turned the Profundity into the Alliance’s flagship – a modified MC75 star cruiser defended by laser cannons, torpedo launchers and a complement of starfighters.*

We see this exit in [*Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith 17*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader:_Dark_Lord_of_the_Sith_17)

[image: Panel from the comic mentioned above showing the ships of the Exodus Fleet leaving the Mon Calamari homeworld, the large stalk is not visible under the ship]